# $\sup_n |X_n|^p$ in $L^1$ implies convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say $X_n$ is a martingale. By the martingale convergence theorem we know that if $\sup_n E[|X_n|^p] \lt \infty$, $X_n$ converges P-a.s. to some $X_{\infty}$. But why does $E[\sup_n |X_n|^p] \lt \infty$ imply $X_n$ converges in $L^p$? In general $E[\sup_n |X_n|^p ] \leq \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\sup_n E[|X_n|^p]$, so knowing the left hand side is finite doesn't tell me much about the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|X_k| \leq \sup_n |X_n|$. Hence, $E|X_k| \leq E\sup_n |X_n|$ and $\sup_k E|X_k| \leq E\sup_n |X_n|$. Hence, the martinagle converge $P-$ a.s.

$|X_n-X_{\infty}|^{p} \leq 2^{p} (|X_n|^{p}+|X_{\infty}|^{p})\leq 2^{p+1} \sup_n |X_n|^{p}$. Now apply DCT.

Comment: But why does P-a.s. convergence hold?

Comment: Of course, $X_n \to X_{\infty}$ $P-$ a.s implies $|X_n-X_{\infty}|^{p} \to 0$ $P-$ as. Do you have some confusion about the meaning of a.s.. convergence? @Karl

Comment: Sorry, my doubt is that in order to apply DCT, you already need to know P-a.s. convergence of $X_n$ to some $X_{\infty}$. In this case I don't assume any convergence, just the bound on the expectation of the supremum. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Karl I have edited my answer to adsress your concern.

Comment: I apologise, but I still have some problems with your first line, did you mean "Hence $E|X_k| \leq E\sup_n |X_n|$ and $\sup_k E|X_k| \leq E \sup_n| X_n|$"? And does your conclusion follow from applying the Martingale convergence theorem?

Comment: @Karl Sorry about the typo. Yes, I did apply Martingale Convergence Theorem.